# Uneven K-means clustering, identical data in two clusters. Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-computing, k-means, text-classification

I am new to machine learning and want some help in text clustering.
Please suggest on code changes if you feel.

My problem statement is to cluster the input data into multiple clusters. For this I am using tfidfvectorizer,steming, tokenizing and applying k-means algorithm.

In output I am receiving identical data in two different clusters however I want them to be in same.

Please find below sample data that I have and code that I have written.

```
Seat Allocation has been delayed, please wait sometime., Next Update Date : 03/03/2016 16:05:21
Seat Allocation has been delayed, please wait sometime., Next Update Date : 04/05/2018 15:05:21
Seat Allocation has been delayed, please wait sometime., Next Update Date : 05/06/2013 14:05:21
Seat Allocation has been delayed, please wait sometime., Next Update Date : 06/07/2014 13:05:21

Seat Allocation has been delayed., Next Update Date : 06/03/2018 08:44:48
Seat Allocation has been delayed., Next Update Date : 23/02/2018 15:36:18  
Seat Allocation has been delayed., Next Update Date : 08/03/2018 11:19:26
Seat Allocation has been delayed., Next Update Date : 20/03/2018 09:41:21
Seat Allocation has been delayed., Next Update Date : 27/07/2018 11:13:37
Seat Allocation has been delayed., Next Update Date : 22/01/2018 13:46:25

Need background Verification
Need background Verification
Need background Verification
Need background Verification

Sent for verification
Sent for verification
Sent for verification
Sent for verification
```

Data: "Seat Allocation has been delayed...." is going under two different clusters.
e.g.

Data:

```
Seat Allocation has delayed, Next Update Date : 03/03/2015 16:05:21 0
Seat Allocation has delayed, Next Update Date : 03/04/2016 16:05:22 0
```

is going into cluster 0 and

```
Seat Allocation has been delayed, please wait sometime., Next Update Date : 04/05/2018 15:05:21
Seat Allocation has been delayed, please wait sometime., Next Update Date : 05/06/2013 14:05:21
```

is going into cluster 1.

I have tried to reduce and increase the no. of clusters also. Still it is not working. The programming language I used is Python

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.feature_extraction import text
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

data = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\project\\SampleInput.xlsx")  

punc = ['.', ',', '"', "'", '?', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}',"%"]
stop_words = text.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS.union(punc)
desc = data['comments_long'].values
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words = stop_words)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(desc)

word_features = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

#STEMMING and Tokenizing

stemmer = SnowballStemmer('english')
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'[a-zA-Z\']+')

def tokenize(text):
    return [stemmer.stem(word) for word in tokenizer.tokenize(text.lower())]

#vectorization with stop worlds
vectorizer2 = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words = stop_words, tokenizer = tokenize)
X2 = vectorizer2.fit_transform(desc)
word_features2 = vectorizer2.get_feature_names()
print(len(word_features2))
print(word_features2[:50])

vectorizer3 = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words = stop_words, tokenizer = tokenize, max_features = 1000)
X3 = vectorizer3.fit_transform(desc)
words = vectorizer3.get_feature_names()

#kmeans
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
wcss = []
for i in range(1,11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i,init='k-means++',max_iter=300,n_init=10,random_state=0)
    kmeans.fit(X3)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
plt.plot(range(1,11),wcss)
plt.title('The Elbow Method')
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS')
plt.savefig('elbow.png')
plt.show()

true_k = 3
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = true_k, n_init = 20, n_jobs = 1) # n_init(number of iterations for clsutering) n_jobs(number of cpu cores to use)
kmeans.fit(X3)
# We look at 5 the clusters generated by k-means.
common_words = kmeans.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:,-1:-26:-1]
for num, centroid in enumerate(common_words):
    print(str(num) + ' : ' + ', '.join(words[word] for word in centroid))

data_new = pd.DataFrame()
data['Cluster_Id'] = kmeans.labels_
data_new['X']=desc
data_new['Cluster_Id'] = kmeans.labels_
data_new.to_excel('outputNew'+str(true_k)+'test.xlsx',sheet_name='All_Data', index=False)

from openpyxl import load_workbook
book = load_workbook('outputNew'+str(true_k)+'test.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('outputNew'+str(true_k)+'test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

for i in range(true_k):
    data_new[data_new['Cluster_Id']==i].to_excel(writer,sheet_name='cluster'+str(i), index=False)

writer.save()
```

Comment: Create [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How is that data "identical"? The message is clearly different. Seeing your input data, I'd have expected those to go into different clusters. (Depends on the number of clusters, of course)

Comment: Hi tobias_k, thanks for reply.
However, the data may not be exactly identical but the message it shows is same and that is what we are trying to resolve.
We want these kind of data to be in same cluster.
Kindly help us.